# increment two variables with different step sizes in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, iterator

I have two iterators i and j; i starts at 1 and increments by 1 where as j starts at 12 and increments by 30. Is there a way to combine this in a single for loop?

I am looking for a solution that looks something like

```
iLast=41
jLast=1200

for ((i=1,j=12;i=<$iLast,j=<$jLast;i++,j++));do
          COMMAND1
          COMMAND2
done
```

in the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ for ((i=1,j=12; i<= 5 && j<=1000;i+=1,j+=30 ));do echo i=$i j=$j; done
i=1 j=12
i=2 j=42
i=3 j=72
i=4 j=102
i=5 j=132
```

Comment: Thanks! But, copy pasting that line results in this error
```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? Works fine in 3.2 and 4.4, at least.

Comment: 4.2.46 on Centos7

Comment: it worked... must've been sloppy copying on my part